# Share app link to by ActivityViewController iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

My app is not Live yet. I got the app ID from the `App Store Connect`. I want to share the app link on social media apps. I used the `UIActivityViewController`:

```
let string1 = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXX"
let url = NSURL(string: string1)

let shareItems = [UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)]
    
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Problem: It is not showing some social media apps like WhatsApp.

[image]

Comment: what's your problem??
wwhat's app not showing or how to get xxx code??

Comment: in this place use `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/idxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8`

Comment: That will not work. You are trying to put the RESULT of calling a function (VOID) in to an array. What you need to do is simply put the non-optional URL in to the array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is used to open the site, not to share the app:

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)]
```

Do this instead:

```
if let name = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/idxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8"), !name.absoluteString.isEmpty {
  let objectsToShare = [name]
  let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
  self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
  // show alert for not available
}
```

for sample see [this](http://www.codingexplorer.com/sharing-swift-app-uiactivityviewcontroller/)

Comment: Can i use "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXX" in place of "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/idxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8" ?

Comment: is this one for call back method , we diectly check the app is avilable in our device or not else , if you use this one `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/idxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8, it directly redirect to safari

Comment: i seen ?ls=1&mt=8 is changing for some app... i want app download directly form link

Answer (score 22):

**Solution for Swift 4 or better:**

This solution also works on iPad (the solution above crashes on iPad):

```
if let urlStr = NSURL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/idxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8") {
    let objectsToShare = [urlStr]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        if let popup = activityVC.popoverPresentationController {
            popup.sourceView = self.view
            popup.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 4, width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }

    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The URL is changed to "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id\(your app id)"

Comment: If you are not doing it in Viewcontroller, you can use vc by adding "vc: UIViewController" parameter to the function instead of using self.
I used "activityVC" instead of self :) It didn't work, so I'm writing this comment.

Answer (score 8):

The solutions here are all good but it's worth considering implementing the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol and `LinkPresentation` framework.

My solution achieves the following:

- App icon and title showing at the top of the `UIActivityViewController`
- Direct link to App Store for AirDrop `ActivityType`
- Custom text for messages and emails, including an opportunity to add a link to the app on Google Play if required
- Subject for emails
- Doesn't use the `LPMetaDataProvider` fetch request (as described in this [WWDC 2019 262](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/262/) video) so faster to load

### 0. Init the `UIActivityViewController`:

Set the items to `self`:

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Exclude certain `ActivityType`s which don't apply:

```
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList, .assignToContact, .markupAsPDF, .openInIBooks, .saveToCameraRoll]
```

For iPad set the `popoverPresentationController.sourceView` or `.barButtonItem` (this is ignored on iPhone):

```
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = myButton
```

Present it:

```
present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

### 1. Implement the required `UIActivityItemSource` methods

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsource

You must implement the placeholder method which according to the docs:

> Placeholder objects do not have to contain any real data but should be configured as closely as possible to the actual data object you intend to provide.

```
func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
    return ""
}
```

And the actual data, returning a link to the app for AirDrop and text for everything else:

```
func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
    
    if activityType == .airDrop {
        return URL(string: "APP_STORE_URL")!
    }
    
    return "Check out the APP_NAME on the App Store: APP_STORE_URL or on the Google Play Store: PLAY_STORE_URL"
}
```

### 2. Implement the subject method

From the docs:

> For activities that support a subject field, returns the subject for the item.

```
func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
    return "EMAIL_SUBJECT" // e.g. App name
}
```

### 3. Implement the `LPLinkMetaData` method

From the docs:

> Returns metadata to display in the preview header of the share sheet.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
    let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
    metadata.title = "APP_NAME"
    return metadata
}
```

Comment: I had a doubt. If we are sharing link, how can we get the - Add to Reading list option in share sheet for our app? I'm unable to get that option while sharing a link from my app using share sheet.

Comment: @SayaleePoteAs well as manually excluding activity types the system will also remove those that aren't compatible. I don't know what sort of data the system is expecting for adding to reading list though, I would have thought a link would work but it doesn't.

Comment: Just fixed it. A link works. We need to make sure the return type for placeholder is a link for that option to appear. Initially was sending a link but return type for placeholder was an empty string which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**iPhone** solution for **Swift 5+**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1535629801")!
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
present(vc, animated: true)
```